How to embed the content of a webpage into its URL?
When I create a text QR code and scan it with a phone, the phone puts the text in a browser and the default behavior is to search for the text.
I just want the text displayed. There is a web site that will accommodate this situation (QRstuff.com), but I would rather not depend on that for a “memorial” that may be around longer than any given company.
Since I can depend on a phone to follow a IRL, Is there a URL structure that will display text from the URL without an external link? I haven’t found anything like this.
I have tried just using html:
<a href=“”>Hello World!</a>

This just searches for the text.
data:text/html,<h1>Hello World!</h1>

This works if entered directly into the browser, but breaks when a phone reads the QR code.
HTTP://data:text/html,<h1>Hello World!</h1>

This site can’t be reached.

Related: Is it possible to put a data URL in a QR code?
